# "Uncaught ReferenceError: cosole is not defined" in Firebase JavaScript authentication

Tags: firebase-authentication

Here is the problem:

[image]

Html code:

[image]

JS Code:

[image]

Comment: Please replace the links to images with text with the actual text. That will significantly improve chances that someone will be able and willing to help.

Comment: "cosole" sounds suspiciously like a typo.